# Python checking account simulator

Tags: python, oop, python-3.x

I have been working on an OOP program in python 3.0 that simulates a checking account and I ran into a bug that i can't figure out. Here it is: In the main part of the program I gave the 
user multiple options such as , exit, withdraw , deposit , and create new account. when the user selects "create new account " the program creates an object and the variable name has to be another variable and im not sure how to access atributes from an object that is labeled  with a variable.basically what i am asking is, how do i make a variable name a variable so that the computer can keep track of it and use it to access attributes of  an object?
here is the program i have so far(if that helps?):

```
class Checking(object):
    """a personal checking acount"""

    def __init__(self , name, balance):
        print("a new checking acount has been created")
        self.name = name
        self.balance = balance


    def __str__(self):
        rep = "Balance Object\n"
        rep += "name of acount" + self.name + "\n"
        rep += "balance is " + self.balance + "\n"
        return rep


    def display(self):
        print("\nyour acount name is ",self.name)
        print("your balance is",self.balance)


    def deposit(self):
        amount = int(input("\nplease enter the amount of money you wish to diposit"))
        self.balance += amount
        print("\nthe balance of 'chris' is ", self.balance)

    def withdraw(self):
        amount = int(input("\nplease enter the amount you wish to withdraw "))
        while amount > self.balance:
            print("is an invalid amount")
            amount = int(input("\nplease enter the amount you wish to withdraw "))
        self.balance -= amount
        print("\nthe balance of 'chris' is ", self.balance)






    answer = None

    while answer != "0":
        answer = input("""what action would you like to take?
        0 exit
        1 deposit
        2 withdraw
        3 add an acount""")
        if answer == "1":
            input("ener your PIN").deposit()
        if answer == "2":
            input("enter your PIN ").withdraw()
        if answer == "3":
            input("enter num") = Checking(name = input("\nwhat do you want your acount name to be?"), balance = 0)
            input("enter you PIN").display()
            print(Checking)

    input("\n\npress enter to exit")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a dictionary; store accounts in a `accounts` dictionary with the acount number as the key:

```
accounts = {}

# ...
if answer == 3:
    account_number = input("enter num")
    account_name = input("\nwhat do you want your acount name to be?")
    accounts[account_number] = Checking(name=account_name, balance=0)
```

Now you can list all accounts a user has, for example:

```
for account_number, account in accounts.items():
    print('Account number: {}, account name: {}'.format(account_number, account.name))
```

etc.

Using local variables for a variable number of items that are all the same is never a good idea. In that case use lists or dictionaries instead.

Comment: i wasn't really sure how to accept i was just clicking buttons

Comment: one question i have is: how do i access the attributes through the account number?

Comment: @vitruvianrockman: `accounts[someaccountnumber]` returns the `Checking` instance you stored in the dictionary associated with the `someaccountnumber` key.